# Why do I get `warning: control reaches end of non-void function` with switch-case?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, warnings, clang++

Consider code like this:

```
enum class Foo
{
    A, B
};

int deliverPizza(Foo foo)
{
    switch (foo) {
    case Foo::A:
        return 0;
    case Foo::B:
        return 1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    return deliverPizza(Foo::A);
}
```

Compiled with `$ g++ -o main main.cpp -Wreturn-type`:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int deliverPizza(Foo)’:
main.cpp:14:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

Why is this? As far as I can see all the cases are handled within the switch. Is it that GCC doesn't understand that the cases return?

On the other hand adding `default` makes `Clang` to warn about `Default label in switch which covers all enumeration values`.

Comment: Did you try giving a `default` case for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still run into UB when you construct the `enum` instance via a cast expression.

```
return deliverPizza(static_cast<Foo>(42));
```

This is allowed and happily compiles. I guess the warning is pedantic with respect to such a scenario.